# How to edit files in AWS S3 in the browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, text-editor

I have hosted my Homepage over Amazon's S3 system. In order to change information on the page, currently, I have to change the file on my computer and upload the new version. However, I would like to directly change the file in the S3 bucket within a browser (to change it anywhere).

Is there a cloud-based text editor that can use S3 as a "file system" and would allow me to change text files (e.g., html, css, js, etc.)?

Comment: You can use s3edit.com It works on browser and can edit files

Answer (score 36):

I would use `S3 Sync` from the `awscli` to download the files and edit them locally before syncing them back to their original location and updating the originals.

Documentation on S3 sync here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

EDIT: Example:

1. `aws s3 sync s3://mybucket .`
2. edit your files locally
3. `aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket`

Comment: This is the best answer on here. You can't edit s3 files directly in s3.

Comment: An example of downloading a file and then uploading it would improve this answer a lot

Answer (score 18):

If you use VSCode and install the *AWS extension*, you can:

1. Open the desired bucket in S3 in the AWS Explorer that you get in your VSCode window
2. Right-click the desired file in the AWS Explorer, and select "Download As...", select the location, and press "Download"
3. Edit your file locally
4. Right-click again the file in the AWS Explorer and select "Upload to Parent...", select the file, and press "Upload"

Comment: This extension is awesome. Thanks for the suggestion - it has exactly the functionality I was looking for!

Comment: This is awesome. I just wish you were able to search for files with a speciffic name as we have thousands of files in our buckets.

Comment: Such a wonderful tip!

Comment: I gotten access to my aws s3 via `AWS Toolkit` via VSCode. Do you mean `AWS Toolkit` instead of AWS?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not currently an AWS-supported method of editing an S3 file within the browser (like you can in, say, cPanel).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the free [CloudBerry Explorer for Amazon S3](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/download-thanks.aspx?prod=cbes3free) to browse, set up your buckets, upload, download and **edit** your files directly from S3

CloudBerry [announced](http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2012/01/how-to-edit-multiple-files-with.html) comfortable multible files editing and automatic upload of your changes.

**EDIT**

If you need a web-based editor you might want to have a look at this [browser editor](http://www.karamasoft.com/ultimateeditor/samples/contenthandling/editorcontentamazons3/editorcontentamazons3.aspx).
Apparently it is capable to read files from a s3 bucket, but requires to be installed in your own web space.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a Cloud-based editor. You have to download and install it - and it's not available for Macs. It's not better than a text editor where I upload the changed files via the web interface of S3.

Comment: If a solution installed on your own web space would help you can try [this editor](http://www.karamasoft.com/ultimateeditor/samples/contenthandling/editorcontentamazons3/editorcontentamazons3.aspx)

Comment: thats so annoying there should have been some way to edit

Comment: s3 doesn't support editing files... it stores objects that must be rewritten any time you want to update them. Look into file gate if you want something close.