# amazon ec2 hangs while editing text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi I am beginner in AWS services. For my rails application , I am using micro and medium instances . One of my instance is micro in that I cannot use any text editor like nano,vim, joe its hangs out while trying to open any text file even its less than 100 kb. While trying to copy files by scp also it stalled. In other instances text editors works well. This is the log file I got while trying to to copy file from EC2 to my local...

I have found that in my office network the ssh between my terminal and EC2 seems slow . In my house its working good....

```
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 52
Sending file modes: C0664 103506 home_controller.rb
debug2: channel 0: written 52 to efd 6
Sink: C0664 103506 home_controller.rb
home_controller.rb                              0%    0     0.0KB/s - stalled
```

help me ...

Comment: Could you explain how you connect to your ec2 instance? And what tools you used to download that file? And how you got that log?

Comment: I have found that in my office network the ssh between my terminal and EC2 seems slow . In my house its working good....

Comment: How do you get that error log if you connect via ssh?

Answer (score 1):

If you are locking up your interface when you are trying to edit a file, it is not going to be performance related.  My guess is that it's something to do with your terminal settings.  What client side program are you using to connect to your instance?  Putty? Mac OS X Terminal? Ubuntu Xterm?  I would check to see if you have an appropriate terminal configured.

Try echo $TERM and see what it gives you.  You should also look in /var/log/messages to see if it's reporting any kind of issues.

Comment: I have found that in my office network the ssh between my terminal and EC2 seems slow . In my house its working good....I am using ubuntu terminal, and .pem key to connect using ssh

Answer (score -1):

You can use the free CloudBerry Explorer for Amazon S3 to browse, set up your buckets, upload, download and edit your files directly from S3ץ

See this link: [How to edit files in AWS S3 in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081177/how-to-edit-files-in-aws-s3-in-the-browser)

Comment: Its not S3 bucket its EC2 instance