# Can't access Wordpress due to a misused of html in php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My site built on WordPress.
I have added some html code in php file via Appearance -> edit.
Now my site is down, and showing

> "domain.com page isn’t working
>
> www.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.500"

Now I can't access to wp-admin. How can I access to the file so I can remove that html code?

Comment: provide detail of content which you've placed in file., may be some closing tags is missed or termination statement or something like that

Comment: I have placed <p>....php....</p> :(

Comment: AWS should provide a 'Control Panel' of sorts so there should be a option to navigate to the hosted files through the use of file manager or something similar. I have not used AWS before but with experience using other Web Hosting platforms you could edit the files stored on the system so you ultimately remove that HTML code you added. You could try this [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081177/how-to-edit-files-in-aws-s3-in-the-browser) to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit theme files? If yes, log in through ftp, in your theme folder, make a backup of your theme, then replace your theme with the existing theme.

Comment: I edited functions.php file. My site is hosted on AWS. And I am quite new with AWS and hosting stuff, so I am still figuring it out how does AWS work (my friend helped me with hosting and now he's gone). Do you have any video about how to fix this to suggest me,sir?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp

Comment: Yes, that is a theme file.

@Chris already gave a link. What you have to do is, from your replace the theme folder.