# File editor with s3 support

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, text-editor

Are there any simple open source text editors (that can be hosted on ec2) with amazon s3 support? The use case would be uploading files and editing .md files.

I've seen [cloudberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081177/how-to-edit-files-in-aws-s3-in-the-browser) but I'm looking for something that can be self hosted and accessed from any device.

Comment: Have you considered using [AWS Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit files in AWS S3 in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081177/how-to-edit-files-in-aws-s3-in-the-browser)